# Modal with table not showed in right way

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I am developing an application with laravel 8 and livewire.
In my management view.blade.php I need to show within a modal, a table that I dynamically populate using a script.
The modal that I call has the `id = "showPagamentiModal"`, and when in the view `gestionale.blade.php` I click on the button `Pagamenti` the modal opens, but is displayed as in the attached screen.
How can I show the table inside the modal? Do you have any suggestions?
unfortunately all the attempts made have led me to the same result as the attached screen.

HERE MY CODE:

- gestionale.blade.php

```
{{-- Extends layout --}}
@extends('layout.layout2')


{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row page-titles mx-0">
            <div class="col-sm-6 p-md-0">
                <div class="welcome-text">
                    <h4>Sei sul gestionale di {{ $idt }}</h4>
                    <span>Qui sono listate pratche, partite e articoli</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- import del componente gestionale header filter per i filtri -->
            <livewire:gestionale-header-filter>
            <!-- fine import del componente gestionale header filter -->
            <hr />
            <!-- import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
            <livewire:table-pratiche />
            <hr />
            <livewire:table-partite />
            <hr />
            <livewire:table-articoli />
            <!-- fine dell'import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
            <!-- import del component contenente i button per aprire i modal -->
            <livewire:gestionale-modal-component />

    </div>
    <!-- Inizio dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
    <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un pagamento -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="PagamentoLongModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Aggungi un pagamento</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                    <div class="basic-form">
                        <form method="POST" action="#">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Ente</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Ente" value=""
                                        disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Partita</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Partita" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno Rif.</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno Riferimento"
                                        disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Numero</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Numero" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Carico</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Carico" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Tipologia</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Tipologia">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Imposta</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Imposta">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali imposta"
                                        maxlenght="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mora</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Mora">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali mora"
                                        maxlength="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Pagamento</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Registrazione</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Note</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email" minlength="3"
                                        maxlength="255">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un assegnatario -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="assegnatarioModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Aggiungi un assegnatario</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Seleziona assegnatari (tieni premuto shift per una selezione multipla):</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control input-rounded" id="sel2">
                                    @if (!empty($users))
                                        @foreach ($users as $u)
                                            <option value="{{ $u->id }}">{{ $u->username }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Data Assegnazione</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Data Assegn.">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- modal per visualizzare i pagamenti associati alla partita -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ShowPagamentiModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Pagamenti associati alla partita</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive-sm">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Ente</th>
                                        <th>Minuta</th>
                                        <th>Minuta partita</th>
                                        <th>Anno rif.</th>
                                        <th>Agente Riscossione</th>
                                        <th>Anno ruolo</th>
                                        <th>#ruolo</th>
                                        <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
                                        <th>Denominazione</th>
                                        <th>ID cartella</th>
                                        <th>Carico €</th>
                                        <th>Progressivo riscossione</th>
                                        <th>Data pagam.</th>
                                        <th>Data reg.</th>
                                        <th>Tipo pagam</th>
                                        <th>Modalità pagamento</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <div class="modal-body-table">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Stampa</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- modal per visualizzare le procedure e le inesigibilita associati alla partita -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"
        id="ProcedureInesigibilitaModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Procedure e Inesigibilit&agrave;</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere il corpo del body -->
                    <p>Body da aggiungere, da capire i dati da mostrare a video</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Stampa</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fine dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
    <script>
        //SCRIPT PER L'APERTURA DINAMICA DEI MODAL A SECONDA CHE SIANO SELEZIONATE O MENO LE OPPORTUNE RIGHE DELLE TABELLE NELLA PAGINA
        // INIZIO ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'AGGIUNGI PAGAMENTO'
        window.addEventListener('openPagamentoLongModal', event => {
            $(".modal-body").empty();
            $(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" hidden name="id_articolo" id="articolo" placeholder="' + event.detail.id_articolo + '" value="'+event.detail.id_articolo+'"/>');
            $("#PagamentoLongModal").modal('show');
        })
      
        window.addEventListener('closePagamentoLongModal', event => {
            $("#PagamentoLongModal").modal('hide');
        })
        // FINE ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'AGGIUNGI PAGAMENTO'
    
        // INIZIO ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'AGGIUNGI ASSEGNATARIO'
        window.addEventListener('openassegnatarioModal', event => {
            $(".modal-body").empty();
            $(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" hidden name="id_pratica" id="pratica" placeholder="' + event.detail.id_pratica + '" value="'+event.detail.id_pratica+'"/>');
            $("#assegnatarioModal").modal('show');
            console.log(event.detail.id_pratica);
        })
      
        window.addEventListener('closeassegnatarioModal', event => {
            $("#assegnatarioModal").modal('hide');
        })
        // FINE ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'AGGIUNGI ASSEGNATARIO'
    
        // INIZIO ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'PAGAMENTI ASSOCIATI'
        window.addEventListener('openShowPagamentiModal', event => {
            // Qui dobbiamo passare la lista dei pagamenti associati alla partita
            $(".modal-body-table").empty();
            
            $(".modal-body-table").append('<tr>');
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].ente+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].id_minuta+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].id_minuta_partita+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].annoRif+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].agenteRiscossione+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].annoRuolo+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].numeroRuolo+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].codiceFiscale+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].denominazione+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].identificativoCartella+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].carico+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].progressivoRiscossione+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].dataPagamento+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].dataRegistrazione+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].tipoPagamento+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('"<td>'+event.detail.pagamenti[0].modalitaPagamento+'</td>"' );
            $(".modal-body-table").append('</tr>');
           
            $("#ShowPagamentiModal").modal('show');
        })
      
        window.addEventListener('closeShowPagamentiModal', event => {
            $("#ShowPagamentiModal").modal('hide');
        })
        // FINE ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'PAGAMENTI ASSOCIATI'
    
        // INIZIO ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'PROCEDURE/INESIGIBILITA'
        window.addEventListener('openProcedureInesigibilitaModal', event => {
            // Qui dobbiamo passare la lista delle procedure e inesigibilita associate
            //$(".modal-body").append('<input type="text" hidden name="id_partita" id="partita" placeholder="' + event.detail.id_partita + '" value="'+event.detail.id_partita+'"/>');
            $("#ProcedureInesigibilitaModal").modal('show');
        })
      
        window.addEventListener('closeProcedureInesigibilitaModal', event => {
            $("#ProcedureInesigibilitaModal").modal('hide');
        })
        // FINE ACTION PER APERTURA E CHIUSURA DINAMICA DEL MODAL 'PROCEDURE/INESIGIBILITA'
    
    
      </script>
    <!--   IMPORTANTE: AGGIUNGERE IL CSRF TOKEN PRIMA DI ANDARE IN PRODUZIONE -->

@endsection
```

MY SCREEN:
[image]

Comment: are you sure the code is triggered? if you put a console log can you see the log?

Comment: @Jack, yes it's triggered, i've putted two console log, one before $('.modal-body').empty() e one after $("#ShowPagamentiModal").modal('show'); and both are displayed on my console

Comment: @Jack I noticed that if I try to print the whole table using javascript, the data is put in the form of a table, but the bootstrap style is lost and a styleless table results

Comment: i think you should be working with the css of what you want to print

Comment: @feisalramar i've tried to work with my css, but the result doesn't change, i also tried to print the whole table code using JS and removing it from the modal, but still i get the same result ... could it be that my style is bootstrap mounted as laravel project? it is not a pure html style